# Trackpad driver of lenovo thinkbook 15-IML

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo

I have purchased new laptop lenovo thinkbook 15-IML and i have decided to move away from windows. So, i installed ubuntu 20.04 but since this is my first experience i don't know how to install trackpad drivers.

Comment: Don't expect "drivers". All drivers are in Linux kernel. If something doesn't work, it is not supported unless the drivers has been added to a newer kernel, or is in development.

Comment: @Pilot6 i can't afford a windows license, is there any other option for me where i can take full advantage of my system.

Comment: Another option is to wait a few months till the hardware is supported. You could check it before you bought it by booting from a LiveUSB.

Comment: well in this case i better wait now.

Comment: But wifi should start working very soon. This is some minor bug, it is a matter of days.

Comment: where can i get the information about the availability of the drivers.

Comment: There is no specific place. kernel mailing list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Thinkbook 15-IML and experienced exactly the same problem. Lenovo did not provide a solution for this "simple" task. As mentioned in another post, it is not rocket science and solution should have been provided by Lenovo Support Team since it is a basic functionality that should be guaranteed to work on any OS.

Anyway, Ubuntu community and its helpers are pretty amazing. After a few months struggling with the problem, Kai Heng-Feng found a solution and provided a test kernel which solved the issue. Now my touchpad is working.

You can apply the test kernel published in comment #88 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277

To apply this kernel you should download it and then go to Download folder and write the following comand on a terminal:

`sudo dpkg -i linux-image-5.9.0-rc4+_5.9.0-rc4+-4_amd64.deb`

Restart your computer, and enjoy your working touchpad!

P.D: I believe this solution works for a Lenovo Thinkbook IIL series as well. Maybe the permanent solution will be published in a future Ubuntu official kernel.