# Trackpad and Fingerprint Driver Issue - Lenovo Thinkbook 15-IML (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

The trackpad and fingerprint drivers on my Thinkbook 15-IML don't seem to be working. I've tried it on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. It was rumored that 20.10 would have better support but even after the upgrade, the option to sign in with fingerprint does not show up in settings.

I tried the solution offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247520/trackpad-driver-of-lenovo-thinkbook-15-iml) and it worked temporarily (for my trackpad alone) before ruining my kernel eventually.

I was wondering if anyone with the Thinkbook IML series had better luck than I did.

Comment: Many of the current fingerprint drivers for Lenovo devices will work with *swipe-style* readers, but the Thinkbook 15 ships with a *touch-style*. There is work on making these devices work, but there isn't anything just yet.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate! Is there a forum of some kind where I can keep track of this issue? @Matigo

Comment: Fingerprint in ThinkBook 14s also doesn't work